# "Спасибо, что потерпели" (например, стоматолог - пациенту)

Tags: лексика, лексическая-сочетаемость

Скажите, нормально ли составлена фраза или желательно перефразировать, поскольку есть устоявшееся выражение "потерпеть неудачу" (поражение, крах и т.д.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вне контекста эта фраза воспринимается как извинение за задержку (= *спасибо, что подождали*). В буквальном своём значении она уместна в *кратковременной* ситуации, когда стоматолог предупредил, что обезболивания при какой-то манипуляции не получится. В контексте же прощания стоматолога с пациентом лучше "спасибо за терпение".

Answer (score -1):

В данном контексте фразу вряд ли можно счесть двусмысленной. Не вижу необходимости что-то менять в угоду сомневающимся. "Потерпеть неудачу" устойчивый оборот (кстати, не достигший пока уровня фразеологизма), но это никак не сказывается на возможности использовать слово "потерпеть" в другом контексте, пусть и в подобном значении.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — из очереди проверок

Answer (score -1):

Не говорят спасибо за то, что кто-то потерпел боль. Это звучит странно.

За принесённые неудобства принято извиняться: *Извините, что пришлось потерпеть.*

Или можно похвалить за терпение. В контексте пациента-ребёнка хорошо звучит: *Молодец, что потерпел.*